# Is a DNS Lookup performed in this case?

Tags: domain-name-system, ip

Sorry for this noob question in advance :-)

When I enter a dedicated IP of a web server in the browser instead of a domain name, then as far as I know my computer does not need to perform a DNS lookup, am I right? But what about if the IP has also an additional path? There's also no DNS lookup needed, right?
So for example:

```
http://123.123.123.123/        --> No need for a DNS lookup
http://123.123.123.123/~asdf/  --> Also no lookup?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still no look up in this case.
whatever is after the / in your url is meaningless for dns, it is just a page address on the server. DNS is just there for your browser to find the server. 
Apache (or whatever web server your using) will be in charge of finding the ressource.